# XNA Sprite.bounds.contain(x,y) wont return an answer

Tags: c#, xna, sprite

I just play around with XNA and when I wanted to click on a sprite and something happen, I put this code:

```
if(Mouse.GetState().LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed)

{

        if (sprite.Bounds.Contains(Mouse.GetState().X, Mouse.GetState().Y))
          {
              this.Exit();
          }
}
```

how ever when I hover over the sprite with my mouse and click nothing happens, why?

And how do I fix this?

If this helps I wrote my 2D sprite in a rectangle

Comment: Does `Bounds` refer to the sprite's _location on the screen_, or its _location on the texture_?  I suspect it's the latter.

Comment: It's the location on the screen I'm looking for. Bounds says it gets the size of the resourse. And I was using contains() to find a point by it's X, and Y, axis. In this case the mouse point. If this Helps.

Comment: Oh Anddrew I used the debugger with stops and my problem is I can't get the `bool sprite.Bounds.Contains(Mouse.GetState().X, Mouse.GetState().Y`     to equal true. That's my problem with the code I'v written

Comment: @JayVanSchaick, what does the `Bounds` property of your sprite look like? The [XNA Rectangle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.rectangle_members.aspx) structure doesn't have a `Bounds` property, so I assume you've written this yourself...

Comment: @Simon McKenzie, The `Bounds` property "gets the size of the resource," which in this case it a sprite. And, Yes I have written the code my self.

Comment: @JayVanSchaick, as @ColeCampbell mentioned, it sounds like the `Bounds` property isn't correctly returning the sprite's _screen_ coordinates - maybe it's returning its coordinates relative to its parent or a texture, or maybe it's not incorporating its current position at all. Put a breakpoint on your problem line and inspect the values of `Bounds` and the mouse state (i.e what are the coordinates and size of the bounds, and what are the coordinates of the mouse), or if you still can't work it out, post the code from your `Bounds` property in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Please confirm that Bounds is calculated as such:

```
public Rectangle Bounds
{
    get
    {
        return new Rectangle(position.X - width / 2, position.Y - height / 2, width, height);
    }
}
```

I also suggest getting a reference to Mouse.GetState() a single time per update instead of calling it as needed.

Answer (score 0):

`Texture.Bounds` does not put the rectangle in the texture's place, the values of X and Y are both equal to 0.

You would have create your own rectangle to do `.Contains()` on based on your `SpriteBatch.Draw()` inputs.

[image]

The texture "logoTexture" is somewhere near the bottom left corner of the screen.